# Why is the Signature section of my Haddock generated documentation home page empty?

Tags: haddock

I'm generating documentation for my Haskell library using:

```
stack haddock --no-haddock-deps
```

And the resultant *index.html* page has an empty *Signatures* section.

Why is the *Signatures* section empty?

Comment: Does your library contain Backpack signatures? If yes, can you give us a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @sjakobi, I now understand that the *Signatures* section is populated with a module's *Backpack* signatures, which my module lacks. So, I shouldn't expect any content in that section.